# Значение фамилии Беневоленская

Tags: ономастика

Объясните, пожалуйста, значение фамилии Беневоленская.

Answer (score 3):

Придуманная в семинариях фамилия с латинскими корнями. По-латыни "беневоленс" — проявляющий добрую волю. Так иногда называли юношей, поступивших в семинарию по собственной воле, а не по настоянию родителей.